# Composing a list of pairs

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I have a list in Scala as the following: `List(1,2,3,4)`

How can I generate a list of tuples of all the pairs of elements running up so I would end up with a result as follows:

`List((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4))`

Is there a built in function that could produce such a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `combination` method in List, that does exactly this

```
List(1,2,3,4).combinations(2).toList
```

Comment: Just a side note, this creates a list of lists and not a list of tuples but it's good enough

Answer (score 1):

you could use a for comprehension

```
for {
  x <- list
  y <- list
} yield { (x,y) }
```

Comment: This also creates elements I didn't want like `(1,1)`